# UserName for all application in a Domain

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

Requirement- I want to list all the machine name in a domain where my userid/username is being used in any of the system application(like in Virtual Directory etc.) using VBScript

Please suggest the appropriate way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. WMI is an interface to system information, usually called via VBS:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18928/Gather-Information-about-Domain-PCs-using-WMI

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to scrape the authentication logs of your domain controllers.